# Textures appear to be intersecting faces but the geometry

Tags: mesh, materials

im not sure on the terminology but look at the images the textures are messed up near the tip i looks like faces are going through each other but as you can see the normals are all correct no faces are intersecting and every face is a quad no ngons  only quads if someone could explain that would be great how to fix it and also why it is happening in the first place so i can stop it in the future thanks [image]e[image]

Comment: I think you need to upload your file. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com'

Comment: could you please show what part bothers you? It looks normal

Comment: Looks like those big faces in the middle are skewed. As in not all the verts are close to even, so the face is bent out of shape. Try fixing that, or giving the area 1 or 2 more loops to break up that face a bit.